# Geoserver NGINX configuration

Tags: amazon-ec2, geoserver, nginx-location, nginx-config

I'm new to Nginx and EC2 and trying to add some simple authentication as below. It's a one page app and i want to secure the access to the page but not the tile server. With no authentication all works well. With authentication as the below I get back an error saying;

`http://map.domain.org.uk is requesting your username and password. The site says: “GeoServer Realm”`

I think this is because I've set authentication for any location and the tiles sit under that. How would I set up to just require authentication for the equivalent of a landing page?

```sh
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/domain.org.uk/public_html;

    index index.html;

    server_name domain.org.uk www.domain.org.uk map.domain.org.uk;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/domain.org.uk.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/domain.org.uk.error.log;

  # auth_basic "Server level Password required to proceed";
   # auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/.htpasswd;

    location /geoserver/gwc/service/wmts {
      auth_basic off;
#also tested without auth_basic off;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts;
    }


    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    auth_basic "Location level Password required to proceed";
   auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/.htpasswd;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?request=GetCapabilities`

Also, I think [This](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/security/tutorials/digest/index.html) is useful for you in this case.

This uses `curl` utility to issue `HTTP` requests that test authentication. Install curl before proceeding.

Also, check `/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com` [Here](https://www.linode.com/docs/uptime/loadbalancing/use-nginx-as-a-front-end-proxy-and-software-load-balancer/) on **Linode**.

Example

`upstream appcluster{
   server linode.example.com:8801;
   server linode.example.com:8802 weight=1;
}`

Comment: Thanks but as OP I know that the request is fine without authentication so this is not the error, it's a config setting for geoserver of nginx that I need to understand